# tengo este array de numeros que una vez desordenados los numeros quiero que se metan en tres filas de 5 numeros cada fila, como puedo hacerlo?

Tags: javascript

una vez desordenados los numeros deverian meterse en el array multidimensional nombrado numSort para que se vea una tabla de tres filas por cinco numeros cada fila, pero estoy un poco atascado y no se como hacerlo.

```
let bingonumCard = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
let numSort = [[],[],[]];
let bingoCard = () => {
  
  for (let i = 0; i <= bingonumCard.length; i++) {
    
      bingonumCard = bingonumCard.sort(function () { return Math.random() - 0.5 });
      numSort.push(bingonumCard.sort);
      }
    
    
  
  console.table(numSort);
}
bingoCard();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma de lograrlo es con la función [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), que devuelve una parte de un Array, alterando el original.

Adicionalmente, he mejorado un poco la función para hacerla *reutilizable*.

Asumiendo que tu Array siempre tiene 15 elementos, y sacarás 3 grupos de 5 elementos, una forma de aplicar esto sería:

```js
// elementos del Array
let bingonumCard = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
// función que sirve para desordenar un Array (no altera el original)
let shuffle = list => {
  return [...list].sort(function () { return Math.random() - 0.5 });
}

// función que devuelve un Array con grupos del tamaño especificado
let bingoCard = (list, groupSize) => {
  // desordenamos la lista recibida
  let unordered = shuffle(list);
  // calculamos cuantos grupos se van a armar
  let groups = parseInt(list.length / groupSize);
  // si hay menos elementos que el tamaño del grupo devolvemos todo el array
  if(groups < 1) return unordered;
  // array donde se almacenarán los grupos
  let arr = [];
  // por cada grupo incluimos los primeros elementos del array
  for (let i = 0; i < groups; ++i) {
    arr.push(unordered.splice(0, groupSize));
  }
  // si hay elementos sobrantes, se añaden al array
  if (unordered.length) arr.push(unordered);
  return arr;
}

// ejemplo de agrupación en grupos de 5 elementos
let numSort_5 = bingoCard(bingonumCard, 5);
console.log('Grupos de 5:');
console.log(numSort_5.join(' - '));

// ejemplo de agrupación en grupos de 3 elementos
let numSort_3 = bingoCard(bingonumCard, 3);
console.log('Grupos de 3:');
console.log(numSort_3.join(' - '));

// ejemplo de agrupación en grupos de 2 elementos
let numSort_2 = bingoCard(bingonumCard, 2);
console.log('Grupos de 2:');
console.log(numSort_2.join(' - '));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo que solo serán 15 numeros, esta es una forma:

```js
let bingonumCard = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
let numSort = [[],[],[]];

let i = 0;

bingonumCard.forEach( (val, index) => {
   if( index % 5 == 0 ){
      i=0;
      numSort[parseInt(index/5)][i++]=val
   } else {
      numSort[parseInt(index/5)][i++]=val
   }
})

// lo mostramos fila por fila

numSort.forEach( (val, sub) => {
   console.log(val+" ");
});
```